# What size header for a 2' window opening exterior wall , two floors and a roof in a 40psf snow load area?

Tags: windows

What size header is need for a 2' opening in a load bearing wall.

I have room for 2 x 6 on edge, not sure if need LSL or LVL, not having luck finding 2 x 6 LVL beams.

2 floors and a roof.
snow load = 40 PSF
2 x 6, 24 OC walls
2 x 6, 16 OC support ( will be removing one  2 x 6 for window opening.

Thanks

Comment: By on edge, do you mean laying flat(1.5 inches between the window and top plate)?

Comment: On edge I mean 5 1/2 inches between the window and top plate for 2 x 6.